# Which is the correct Hessian matrix (the standard matrix of a bilinear form)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Please note the typo in the first entry: $\frac {\partial^2f} {\partial x_1\partial x_2}$ should instead be $\frac{\partial^2f} {\partial x_1\partial x_1}$.

Also, this Hessian matrix need not be symmetric as the partials need not all be continuous.

The convention in use is: $\frac {\partial^2f} {\partial x_1\partial x_2}$ means $\partial_{x_1} (\partial_{x_2}f)$.

> Question: Shouldn't the correct matrix be the transpose of what is
> given?
>
> My reasoning is this:
>
> Let $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Because the matrix is for the bilinear form
> $D^2f(x)$, by definition, the $ij$-entry of the matrix is given by
> $$[D^2f(x)](e_i,e_j)=[[D(Df)(x)] (e_i)](e_j) =\frac {\partial^2f} {\partial x_j\partial x_i} \neq \frac {\partial^2f} {\partial x_i\partial x_j}.$$ In other words, in the $ij$-entry, the $i$th variable should be partialled before the $j$th variable, not the other way round.

Referring to the proof is not helpful as it is cryptic and makes no sense:
[image]
[image]
Information on how $D^2f(x)$ is defined:
[image]
[image]

Comment: $D^2f(x) (\vec a,\vec b) = D^2f:(\vec a\otimes \vec b) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}a_i b_j$, i.e. $D^2f(x) (\vec a,\vec b) = \vec a^T D^2f(x) \vec b$, so their definition holds.

Comment: Ok, I want to say that when you apply $D^2 f$ to a couple of vectors $\vec a,\,\vec b$, you wrote it as $\langle D^2 f \vec a,\vec b\rangle$, while it should be $\vec a^T D^2f\vec b$, i.e. $\langle D^2f \vec b,\vec a\rangle$. ($\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes scalar product, $D^2f$ is a matrix).

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I wasn't indicating matrix multiplication at all. $D^2f(x)$ here does not refer to the matrix but the bilinear form, and it makes no sense to use the very matrix that we are trying to find, to determine its entries!

Comment: Could you clarify you notation convention: is $\partial_{x_i}(\partial_{x_j}f)$ denoted by $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ or by $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$Let us write $A \subseteq U=V=\mathbb{R}^n$. We have
\begin{align*}
f:& A \to \mathbb{R}\\
Df:& A \to \hom(V,\mathbb{R})\\
D^2f:=D(Df):& A \to \hom(U, \hom(V,\mathbb{R}))
\end{align*}
Note that the codomain of $Df$ is $\hom(V,\mathbb{R})$ (the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$), which is not a Euclidean space. So, what do we mean by $D(Df)$? Since $\hom(V,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, the answer is that we first identify each linear operator $L_i: e_j\mapsto\delta_{ij}$ with the vector $e_i$. Hence the linear map $Df(x)$ is identified with the gradient vector $\nabla f(x)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\,\ldots,\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)^\top$ before taking a second derivative.

Having this identification, the matrix of $D^2f$, *as a linear operator*, is the Jacobian matrix of $\nabla f$, i.e. $J(\nabla f)(x)=\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\right)$. Therefore, $D^2f(x)(u)$ is represented by the vector $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\right)u$ and
$$
\left(D^2f(x)(u)\right)(v) = \left[\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\right)u\right]^\top v = u^\top \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right)v.\tag{1}
$$
Technically, $D^2f(x)$ is *not* a bilinear form, but a linear operator that maps vectors to linear operators. Yet, the mapping $B_x:U\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ by $B_x(u,v)=\left(D^2f(x)(u)\right)(v)$ is bilinear. Therefore we can identify $D^2f(x)$ with the bilinear form $B_x$. And when we speak of the matrix of $D^2f(x):U\times V\to\mathbb{R}$, we actually mean the matrix of $B_x$ (and $D^2f(x)$ is not really a function from $U\times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place).

By convention, if $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ represent respectively two vectors $u,v$ and a bilinear form $b(u,v)$ with respect to some basis, then $b(u,v)=\mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{B}\mathbf{v}$. Therefore, from $(1)$, we see that the matrix of $B_x$ with respect to the standard basis is $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right)$.

Comment: @Ryan Here, $\nabla f$ denotes a vector-valued function and $\nabla f(x)$ denotes a vector. So, I was talking about the Jacobian matrix of the vector-valued function $\nabla f$. Call $\nabla f$ as $g=(g_1,\ldots,g_n)^\top$. Then $g_i(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)$.

Comment: Therefore the Jacobian matrix of $g$ is $(\dfrac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j})=\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\right)$.

Comment: Now $\left(D^2f(x)(u)\right)(v)$ is the dot product of the vector representations of $D^2f(x)(u)$ and $v$. For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, you can write their dot product as $x^\top y=y^\top x$. Therefore you get $(1)$.

Comment: It can't, but I was talking about the dot product of the **vector representations** of $D^2f(x)(u)$ and $v$.

Comment: Anyway, there seem to be quite a few (arbitrary?) representations (eg. identifying linear map with gradient vector, the dot product of vector representations, etc) that I feel that all this is so convoluted. What was wrong with my *directly* forming the matrix of the bilinear form **from definition** anyway? Nobody has yet commented on why my reasoning is wrong/right. If my reasoning in the grey box is not incorrect, then this question is reduced to one of convention/preference, not logic, and that's fine.

Comment: Since you find my answer too convoluted, I will delete it shortly. As to your reasoning, it is hard to judge whether it is correct or not. Although you said you get your answer **from definition**, actually you haven't stated how $D(Df)$ is defined. Note that $Df$ is not an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued function, but a $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$-valued function. So, how its derivative (i.e. $D(Df)$) is defined is crucial to the current question.

Comment: But please just look again at the theorem statement: we are *abusing notation* and treating $D^2f(x)$ as a bilinear form, although I (and yourself) have also given the correct original meaning of $D^2f(x)$. Just accept that all that's required here is the matrix of the $D^2f(x)$ **as a bilinear form**. And every bilinear form B has a standard matrix whose ij-entry is given by $B(e_i,e_j)$ (please refer to the grey box for the meaning of $e_i$). This is the definition I'm talking about! What have I done wrong/right?

Comment: No please don't delete your answer; it is a good and clear summary, and seems consistent with what Marsden is doing. I don't mean that your answer is convoluted, I mean the process that we are undergoing to obtain the standard matrix seems needless (and perhaps even gives contradicting results from just getting it directly from definition; I may be wrong, since I have still not understood how your Jacobian matrix of g in Comment 2 follows from the last eqn in Comment 1).

Answer (score 0):

**If $f$ is twice differentiable (in sense of totally / Frechet differentiable), then the Hessian is symmetric.**

Notice that there is little merit to using the Hessian if $f$ is not twice differentiable but only twice partially twice differentiable.

**Proof of Schwarz's theorem (for twice differentiable function)**

Without loss of generality assume the domain $A = [-1, 1]^2$ is a square, $f$ differentiable on $A$, $\nabla f$ is differentiable at $0$, and $f(0) = 0$ and $\nabla f(0) = 0$. We show that $\partial_y \partial_x f(0) = \partial_x \partial_y f(0)$.
The proof is little bit ugly. The key idea is that you can expand $f(x,y)$ in two way:
\begin{align} 
f(x,y) &= \frac12 \partial_x \partial_x f(0) x^2 + \frac12 \partial_y \partial_y f(0) y^2 +  \partial_y \partial_x f(0) x y + \mathcal o(\|(x,y)\|^2), \\
f(x,y) &= \frac12 \partial_x \partial_x f(0) x^2 + \frac12 \partial_y \partial_y f(0) y^2 +  \partial_x \partial_y f(0) x y + \mathcal o(\|(x,y)\|^2).
\end{align}
Thus, it follows
$$ \partial_y \partial_x f(0) - \partial_x \partial_y f(0) = \mathcal o(1). $$
That is, $\partial_y \partial_x f(0) = \partial_x \partial_y f(0)$.

Let us see, how to get the first expansion. 
Since $\nabla f$ is continuous at $0$, we may assume $\nabla f$ is bounded on $A$ without loss of generality.
Thus, by the Taylor theorem, we have
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= f(0,y) + \int_0^1 \partial_x f(t x, y) \;\mathrm dt \cdot x \\
&= \frac12 \partial_y\partial_y f(0) y^2 + \mathcal o(y^2) + \int_0^1 \partial_x f(t x, y) \;\mathrm dt \cdot x \\
&= \frac12 \partial_y\partial_y f(0) y^2 + \mathcal o(y^2) + \int_0^1 \partial_x \partial_x f(0)tx + \partial_y \partial_x f(0)y \;\mathrm dt \cdot x + \mathcal o(x^2 + y^2) \\
&= \frac12 \partial_y\partial_y f(0) y^2 + \frac12\partial_x \partial_x f(0)x^2 + \partial_y \partial_x f(0)xy + \mathcal o(x^2 + y^2).
\end{align}
Analogously, we have
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= f(x,0) + \int_0^1 \partial_y f(x, ty) \;\mathrm dt \cdot y \\
&= \frac12 \partial_x\partial_x f(0) x^2 + \frac12\partial_y \partial_y f(0)y^2 + \partial_x \partial_y f(0)xy + \mathcal o(x^2 + y^2).
\end{align}
Which had to be proven.